# How do I retrieve a non related model in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am not sure I have formulated the question well. Let me explain.

It is for a language application with a quiz. I want to present the user with 4 possible translations but only one is correct.
I cannot find a way to select the wrong words for the bad answers.

My relevant db tables are like that

```
Word  
 {id=1}

Lang 
 {id=1, lang = fr}
 {id =2 , lang = en})

WordLang 
 {id=1, word_id=1, lang_id=1, name=chat}   
 {id=2, word_id=1, lang_id=2, name=cat}
```

My word model is like

**model/Word.php**

```
public function wordlang()
{
    $this->hasMany('WordLang');
}

public function notword()
{
    return Word::where('id','<>','$id')->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->first();
}
```

So in my view I have

```
question: {{$word->wordlang()->where('lang_id','1')->first()->name}}
```

Possible answers in English:

```
 - {{$word->wordlang()->where('lang_id','2')->first()->name}}   correct one
 - {{$word->notword()->wordlang()->where('lang_id','2')->first()->name}}
 - {{$word->notword()->wordlang()->where('lang_id','2')->first()->name}}
 - {{$word->notword()->wordlang()->where('lang_id','2')->first()->name}}
```

That kind of works but the $id of the word is not passed to the notword function in the word class and not any word is selected including the correct translation.

Comment: shouldn't notword() accept the $id parameter?

Comment: Thanks celilozaur - that was it

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was probably trivial to some but I just could not see it.

in word model

```
public function notword($id)

    {
        return Word::where('id','<>',$id)->orderBy(DB::raw('RAND()'))->first();
    }
```

in view

```
 - {{$word->wordlang()->where('lang_id','2')->first()->name}}   correct one
 - {{$word->notword($word->id)->wordlang()->where('lang_id','2')->first()->name}}
 - {{$word->notword($word->id)->wordlang()->where('lang_id','2')->first()->name}}
 - {{$word->notword($word->id)->wordlang()->where('lang_id','2')->first()->name}}
```

Thanks again cecilozaur